# Look for today() in range D5:AP5 is X in the range D8:AP8

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, date

I used this formula: - Look for "X" in range D8:AP8 = found/not found, which is fine. Formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH("X";NW_Calendar!D8:AP8;0));"Not found";"Found")
```

but I would like to have it like this:

look today() in range D5:AP5 is X in the range D8:AP8 if match= Ok If not match = Not OK

Range D5:AP5 dates (1Month) Range D8:AP8 with X

What I've tried already:

```
=if(NW_Calendar!A8:AP8="X";"Found";"Not Found") & IF(NW_Calendar!A5:AP5="TODAY()";" Ok";" Not Ok"

=if(countif(NW_Calendar!D8:AP8;">X");"Sign up ";"Not Sign up ") & AND(NW_Calendar!D5:AP5=TODAY();NW_Calendar!D8:AP8="X")
```

Have a look on the screenshot, there you can see what I'm trying to say.

[image]

The range is an type date starting from 02-07-2017 -> 05-08-2017 (changing monhtly) I just changed the type date to "02-07-2017" instead of "02.07.2017".

Comment: What are the values of `NW_Calendar!D5:AP5`? Are they of type date, type text or type number? By the way, IMHO a dot should not be used as date separator as some region settings use it as decimal separator.

Comment: The range is an type date starting from 02-07-2017 -> 05-08-2017 (changing monhtly) I just changed the type date to "02-07-2017" instead of "02.07.2017" thanks for the advise

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(D5:AP5=TODAY());--(D8:AP8="X"))=1;"Ok","Not OK")
```

[SUMPRODUCT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094294)